# PayPal IPN Verification and Umlaut

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

i have a problem regarding the PayPal IPN Verification.
The situation is as follows:

I use the IPN Simulator from PayPal Developers to test my IPN PHP Script.
This works perfect and the IPN verify process gives me a "VERIFIED".

But if one variable includes a umlaut i get the "INVALID" status.

Encoding is everywhere set to UTF-8.

The variable that causes the problem is the payment_date which is set to "Wed Jan 20 2016 23:14:37 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)"

From PayPal i get it as `payment_date=Wed%20Jan%2020%202016%2021%3A12%3A07%20GMT%2B0100%20%28Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische%20Zeit%29` 
and thats also the string i send back to PayPal.

If i change this variable in the IPN Simulator to "example" (so there is no umlaut in it) it works perfect.

Can anyone give me an idea how to solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem, but no solution. This has been discussed on the [Issues page](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/issues/51) of the PayPal Github repository for the IPN Sample script.

Answer (score 0):

try decode the date/time so that payment_date is pure date/time in string with space.

See below as a sample.

payment_date=04:58:34 Aug 31, 2016 PDT